# Styling the Discussions List

Tags: jslink, client-side-rendering

I am styling the discussions list web parts using CSR / JS Link. The OOB discussion list contains several buttons that allow you to select various "views", such as *recent*, *what's hot* and *my discussions*, as well as pagination buttons at the bottom:

[image: oob discussion list web part]

Since I am overriding the header/footer template with JS Link, these buttons disappear. Thus I want to add my own buttons. But I can't figure what the original buttons actually do when you click them.

Is it possible to replace these buttons with your own? If not, would it be possible to reload the page with a querystring to show another one of the views?

Comment: Update: I never found a solution for working with these buttons and ended up styling the discussion web parts using pure CSS instead. This compromise looks decent while keeping the functionality of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot , you have shown is nothing but webpart. You can select in web part properties for header = None. Then you can add content editor webpart on top of this and add your own links/Images with styling.

Comment: The problem is not styling. I have my own buttons. The problem is what to do when you click on the buttons? SharePoint calls some ajax to load new content. Can I use this too?